# php result didn't return to html ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, datatables

I have the following code to create a datatable.

Instead of return json result from my php file, it returns the php file itself.

I checked the php file on localhost page and it seems the php file is working fine:

{"draw":0,"recordsTotal":115,"recordsFiltered":115,"data":[{"chr":"chr1","pos":631704},{"chr":"chr1","pos":631714},{"chr":"chr1","pos":631848},{"chr":"chr1","pos":632344},{"chr":"chr1","pos":632461},{"chr":"chr1","pos":633015},{"chr":"chr1","pos":633143},{"chr":"chr1","pos":633300},{"chr":"chr1","pos":633364},{"chr":"chr1","pos":633839},{"chr":"chr1","pos":633852},{"chr":"chr1","pos":633860}............

Could someone help me with it?

I tried this answer by adding

[PHP code is not being executed, but the code shows in the browser source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-but-the-code-shows-in-the-browser-source-code)

```
LoadModule php_module "C:/xampp/php/php8apache2_4.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

but still didn't work.

```
`<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable( {
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {url : "example.php",
                     type: "GET",
                    },
            "columns": [
{ "data": 'chr'},
{ "data": 'pos'}
]
        } );
    } );
</script>`
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding dataType: "json"... I'm also 6 months new with Javascript, let me know if it doesn't work and I'll try something else. I've been working with php for 20 years.

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').DataTable( {
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": {url : "example.php",
                         type: "GET",
                         dataType:"json",
                        },
                "columns": [
    { "data": 'chr'},
    { "data": 'pos'}
    ]
            } );
        } );
    </script>
```

In your PHP script... i'm not familiar with SSP class but couldn't you do something like this? This is how I return json from php to javascript in my game.

```
print json_encode(array("food"=>$_SESSION['food'],"wood"=>$_SESSION['wood'],"gold"=>$_SESSION['gold'],"stone"=>$_SESSION['stone']));
```

and then use data.food in javascript inside function(data){ after ajax call

Comment: I tried to add datatype but it still didn't work. It feels like the php may not be excuted properly.

Comment: whats the php code part of it?

Comment: checking it out, 1 min

Comment: check out my updated answer, if it doesn't work I'll look more into it.

Comment: I am sorry I am new to both Javascript and php. I don't quite understand how to use data.food in ajax call.....do i just replace data : XXX with data.food? it seems it doesn't work...